# Correlation between FT of function constisting of a product and FT of its factors

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Given is as function $ C(x)=A(x)B(x) $ and I want to find the connection between its fourier transforms. So I want to find a function $$ \tilde{C}(k)=\tilde{C}(\tilde{A}(k),\tilde{B}(k)) $$ ($\tilde{}$ stands for Fourier transformation). So basically i want to find out how to write$\tilde{A(x)B(x)}$ in a nice way. I wanted to use the Convolution Theorem $$ \digamma (A*B)= \digamma(A)\digamma(B)$$  (*stand for the convolution between A and B and here $\digamma$ stand for the Fourier Transformation)but there you only have the convolution of A and B fourier transformed and on the other side you have the product but that of the fourier transformed. I hope you can give me a tip.

Comment: It works on both directions : $FT(f \star g)=FT(f).FT(g)$ **and** $FT(f.g)=FT(f) \star FT(g)$ (unlike Laplace Transform).

Comment: ah yeah thank you. Thats also what i just posted ^^. But you didnt write the negative argument. Isnt $ \digamma\digamma((g(x)))=g(-x)$?

Comment: I hadn't to use $g(-x)$ because what I have written doesn't need it. Besides, it's very rare that we apply twice a FT. Usually we apply FT then $FT^{-1}=\overline{FT}$

Comment: okay thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an idea.  I can the $\digamma(A)$and$\digamma(B)$ as A and B and then the Theorem is $$ AB=\digamma(\digamma(A)*\digamma(B))$$ and if you FT then again you get $$\digamma(AB)=\digamma\digamma((\digamma(A)*\digamma(B)))=(\digamma(A)*\digamma(B))(-\bullet)$$
could i do that ?